# Is it possible to set the color on a Card header for a Google Workspace Add On?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I'd like to update the color of the Card header of a Google Workspace Add On I'm developing. Is this possible?

Google has a sample project here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/cats-quickstart#drive.gs. In this screenshot from the sample project page, the Card header is red:
[image]

When I deploy the code, the header is gray and I don't see a way to update Card header color in the docs: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-header

[image]

Is there a way to change the color of the Card header or am I out of luck?

Other Google Workplace Add-Ons I've installed have had different Card header colors. [Zoom](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/zoom_for_google_workspace/364750910244?hl=en&pann=caw) is blue and [GoTo](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/goto_for_google_calendar/973900122739?hl=en&pann=caw) is black.

Comment: Any reason you haven't shown us code? See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this isn't configurable dynamically but set at the project manifest level via [LayoutProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons#common).